# Reload JQGrid edit form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a JQGrid which has add/edit form functionality enabled. Both are working fine. I'm extending the Edit functionality.

I'm adding a custom element to edit form. custom element is ANCHOR TAG with click event defined

1. on click of ANCHOR TAG, I'm doing an ajax call to server and updating some values. until here it is working fine.
2. on successful return, I want reload the edit form with new values.

**My Approach**

On successful return,

1. I reload the grid (working fine) --
    `$('#grid').jqGrid().trigger("reloadGrid");`
2. Close the edit form (working fine) --
   `$('#grid').find('.ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close').click();`
3. reopen the edit form **(not working)**. It opens the same edit form with old values. If I open it manually by clicking edit icon, it refreshes the values. --
   `$('#grid').jqGrid('editGridRow', gr, {Edit params})`

**Question**

Can some one find what why my step 3 not working? And also please let me know if any one have better approach?

Comment: Perhaps you should try triggering the edit icon. I suspect JQGrid caches the form until a different row is selected.

Comment: Thanks Tieson, I figured that out couple of days go. I'll eloberate by answering this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by:

- close existing JQGrid edit form
- set selected row first
- then trigger editGridRow event